# Android Studio ListView onClickItem

Tags: android, xml

Good morning, I am in despair, I can't create a Listener to the list elements.
Should I create a listener that opens me an interface by passing the value of the item clicked, how can I do?
Thank you in advance for your help!

```
package it.a65plus.appseipuntozero;
public class ContactApp extends Activity{
private View mContentView;
private DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
private ContactAdapter adapter;
private ListView listView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_list);
    ArrayList<Contatto> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<Contatto>();
    arrayOfUsers = db.RUB_fetchAllRows();
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    adapter = new ContactAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);
  // Attach the adapter to a ListView
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i,long l) {
            Log.d("Rubrica: ",String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)));
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //toggle();
        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ApplyCycle.activityResumed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ApplyCycle.activityPaused();
}
```

xml_

```
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvUsers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
            </ListView>
```

Adapter

```
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contatto> {
public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contatto> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Contatto user = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    String I=new Integer(user.GetIDAccount()).toString();
    tvName.setText(user.GetUserName());
    tvHome.setText(I);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you be more clear on the question? I really did not understand what are you trying to do

Comment: Thanks for your interest, then the problem is that it does not display anything, despite signs entirely correct in the listener.

Comment: How about we remove this : String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i) and place instead of it this: String.valueOf("Position: "+i)
Since adapterView is a view and it is not logical to cast it entirely into a string

Comment: It does not show anything in debugging, only this:06-30 11:16:14.810 8730-8730/it.a65plus.appseipuntozero D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Comment: As you mentioned "it does not display anything", It means list view is displaying?

Comment: The list is displayed, but not the action of the listener

Comment: @LorenzoLongiave try change the Log.d to this: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem ... uff

Comment: nothing happens @MirianaItani

Comment: @LorenzoLongiave this is very weird but try adding the listener in the adapter convertView.setOnClickListner and show the toast. Also remove the onItemClick listener.

Comment: @MirianaItani what should I change in the adapter?

Comment: private View.OnClickListener mMyButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Row " + position + " was clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Comment: nothing happens @MirianaItani

Comment: someone can show me an correct example?

Answer (score 1):

solved.

```
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contatto> {
public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contatto> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Contatto user = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    String I=new Integer(user.GetIDAccount()).toString();
    tvName.setText(user.GetUserName());
    tvHome.setText(I);
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("putta","lol "+position);
        }
    });
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: here you go, That is actually what I meant. +1 for you